# VBA : how to use the address of the first cell greater than zero

Tags: excel, vba

I have found multiple answers on this question, but I don't know how to apply it to my own worksheet.
First step of code is to sort ascending on column C.
Second step is to find the first cell in column C with a value greater than zero (which should be C7).
What I can't figure out is how to use the address in the second step to cut rows 7, 8 and 9 and paste them on Sheet2

Here's the code so far:

```
Sub findAdres()

' First Step Sort Values

Range("A2:C2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "C:C"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A:C")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

' Second Step find address of first cell in column C greater than zero

Dim lcell As Range

For Each lcell In Range("C2:C100")
  If CLng(lcell.Value) > 0 Then
     not_zero = lcell.Address
     Exit For
  End If
Next lcell

' Third step is cut all rows from row 7 down to end an paste in sheet2
' how do you use the lcell.Address to indicate what you want to cut?

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have `lcell` (defined as `Range`) from previous step, so now you can use it with `Resize`.

```
' Third step is cut all rows from row 7 down to end an paste in sheet2    
' Copy >> Paste in 1 line, to "Sheet2" at "A2"
lcell.Resize(100 - lcell.Row + 1, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
```

**Note**: I am using `100` as last row (same as in your code above).

**Note 2**: if you want, you can replace the `For Each lcell In Range("C2:C100")` loop in step 2, with `Find`.

Comment: Thank you! (I will now go and read up on how "Resize"). Much appreciated.

Comment: @Hernus  now come your part to mark as "ANSWER", by clicking the gray check-mark on the left side of my answer